# Run certain code after a link to another page is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I have a a small piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // OPENS ACCORDIANS WHEN CERTAIN LINKS ARE CLICKED
    $(document).on('click','._jsUpgradeAccordOpen', function() {});

    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#help .checkUpgrade h3").addClass('select')
        $("#help .checkUpgrade .accordianContent").css('display', 'block')
    });
});
```

Basically I have been trying to figure out how to make it when you click ._jsUpgradeAccordOpen it opens an accordian on that page that it redirects to.

I have checked that the content in the load function does work, the problem comes in when you click on the ._jsUpgradeAccordOpen button it is on a different page. So I need to figure out how to execute that code once the page has changed and loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to register a click on one page that effects something on another page you have basically 2 choices. 1. pass it as a query param on the url and read that out in the destination page e.g. in your window.load handler. Or - move to a single page app.

or cookies, or local storage, as Schomz suggests. or server side session or...

UPDATE

probably query param is easiest:

On first page

```
$(element).click(function() {document.location.href = '/newpage?accordion'})
```

On second page

```
$(function () {
var query = window.location.search; //this will be ?accordion
  if query.match('accordion') !== null {
    //show accordion
  }
}
)
```

*untested and approximate

Answer (score 1):

That can't work because the moment you open another page is the moment when you lose everything from the previous one.

To maintain certain element, you can use storages (localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies), or pass a GET/POST variable to the next page, which will you then check for and do the accordion stuff if needed.